# android -How to call a function when keyboard displays

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've an edittext view on my layout . I want to call a function when keyboard is showing and also call another function when keyboard hides.

How can I do so ?

Comment: have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: The methods out there to detect keyboard hide and show are not much reliable. I would suggest using a text watcher on your edit text.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to handle configuration changes yourself.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Sample:

```
// from the link above
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Then just change the visibility of some views, update a field, and change your layout file.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        if(imm.isActive())
        {


            //call your function
        }
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be better if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Please add some explanation or your answer would be removed from SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
     //Hide the keyboard
     ((Activity)mContext).getWindow()
     .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

public static void showKeyboard(Context mContext,EditText edittext){
    //Show the keyboard
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.showSoftInput(edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
}

public static void hideKeyboard(Context mContext,EditText edittext){
    //Hide the keyboard 
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```